# How to insert data from 2 tables in trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to insert in one table from 2 tables with a trigger.

I want to insert in the table Comm_link data from `Opportunity` and `Communication`.

This is my code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[VD_Date_lendemain1]
ON [dbo].[Communication]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comm_Link]
                ([CmLi_Comm_UserId], [CmLi_Comm_CommunicationId],
                 [CmLi_CreatedBy], [CmLi_CreatedDate],
                 [CmLi_UpdatedBy], [CmLi_UpdatedDate],
                 [CmLi_Comm_CompanyId], [CmLi_Comm_PersonId])
        SELECT
            CmLi_Comm_UserId = Comm_CreatedBy,
            CmLi_Comm_CommunicationId = Comm_CommunicationId,
            CmLi_CreatedBy = Comm_CreatedBy,
            CmLi_CreatedDate = Comm_ToDateTime,
            CmLi_UpdatedBy = Comm_UpdatedBy,
            CmLi_UpdatedDate = Comm_UpdatedDate,
            CmLi_Comm_CompanyId = Oppo_PrimaryCompanyId,
            CmLi_Comm_PersonId = Oppo_PrimaryPersonId
        FROM 
            inserted 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.opportunity ON Oppo_OpportunityId = Comm_OpportunityId 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.Comm_Link ON Comm_CommunicationId = CmLi_Comm_CommunicationId
        WHERE 
            Comm_Action = 'Meeting'
END
```

I don't know if it's possible, thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you insert or update data, and the trigger fires, the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain all the data that has been inserted (or updated).

Your trigger should *always* operate only on that data - but currently, you're not using that information in any way. The `Inserted` table will have the exact same structure as the underlying table the trigger is defined on - `Communication` in this case.

So I believe you'd just have to change your `FROM / INNER JOIN` parts of your trigger to something like:

```
    FROM 
        -- same structure as "Communication"
        inserted ins
    INNER JOIN 
        -- I'm assuming here that the "Communication" table has a column
        -- "CommunicationId" which is its primary key
        dbo.opportunity op ON op.Oppo_OpportunityId = ins.CommunicationId
    INNER JOIN 
        -- or maybe you can join the "Comm_Link" table to the 
        -- "Opportunity" table from before - you need to figure that out!
        dbo.Comm_Link cl ON cl.CmLi_Comm_CommunicationId = ins.CommunicationId
```

Since you didn't post your table structures - this is **just a guess**! You need to adapt this to your own situation - but in general, you should **always** make use of the `Inserted` pseudo table to limit the trigger's work to just those rows newly inserted (or updated) - not the whole tables!